# 'ng add @nguniversal/express-engine' not working

Tags: angular-universal

I am learning about [angular universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal). At this step :

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject angular.io-example
```

It is supposed to add some files namely : main.server.ts, but it is not doing anything. I tried the same command with sudo too. What is the problem?

Comment: Same here. Just did not make any change apart from pulling node module.

Comment: I learned it from here 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ86r1zBK8w&t=902s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eenh_XH65CM

probably the only sane source for this.

Answer (score 7):

FYI, I started off with a clean project so there indeed were dependencies missing, your case might be a bit different, depending on whether you already have some of the dependencies already installed.

Since it was doing the same for me too as mentioned, I went ahead and used

`npm i @nguniversal/express-engine`

which showed me some warnings about some dependencies which were missing.

In my case they were,

`npm install ajv-keywords`

and

`npm install @angular/platform-server`

then I ran

`npm install @nguniversal/express-engine`

to install the package, then

`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`

which added the necessary dependencies you were asking for. Hope this is easy to follow

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem on an existing project

It helped me

remove the package node-modules
remove the file package-lock.json
run the command "npm install"
run this command "npm install @nguniversal/express-engine --legacy-peer-deps"
If the package "@nguniversal/express-engine" will be installed, without creating files "server.ts" and "app.server.module.ts", then
run the command "ng add @nguniversal/express-engine"

https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/3017